# NetSuite Loop thru inventorydetail Subrecord Suitescript 1.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript1.0

I'm trying to pull all the listed bin numbers inside the inventorydetail subrecord thru SS1.0. I'm using UE script but I am having trouble looping thru each inventory detail on multiple items:

Scenario:
Item 1 = Inventory Details (Bin1 and Bin2)
Item 2 = Inventory Details (Bin3 and Bin4)

I can pull the bins on item 1 but getting error when the script enters item 2. Please help on my code below:

```
var recordid = nlapiGetNewRecord().getId();
var record = nlapiLoadRecord('itemfulfillment', recordid);
var linenum = record.getLineItemCount('item');

for (var i = 1; i <= linenum; i++) {
    var subrec = record.viewLineItemSubrecord('item', 'inventorydetail', i);
    var invnum = subrec.getLineItemCount('inventoryassignment');

        for (var x = 1; x <= invnum; x++){
            var invitem = subrec.getLineItemText('inventoryassignment', 'binnumber', x);
        
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'invitem ' + invitem);
        
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few reasons that your line may not have an inventory detail record so you need to check if it is empty before accessing it. So something like:

```js
var recordid = nlapiGetNewRecord().getId();
var record = nlapiLoadRecord('itemfulfillment', recordid);
var linenum = record.getLineItemCount('item');

for (var i = 1; i <= linenum; i++) {
    var subrec = record.viewLineItemSubrecord('item', 'inventorydetail', i);
    if(!subrec) {
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'no inventory detail at '+ i);
        continue;
    }

    var invnum = subrec.getLineItemCount('inventoryassignment');
    if(invnum <= 0) {
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'no inventory assignment lines at '+ i);
        continue;
    }

    for (var x = 1; x <= invnum; x++){
            var invitem = subrec.getLineItemText('inventoryassignment', 'binnumber', x);
        
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'invitem ' + invitem);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your input and suggestion make sense. Will definitely add this as my best practice. I also tried the script using 2.0 and was able to make it work.. The problem was on the transaction which causes the error :)

Comment: Glad to help.  If using this code solved the error please mark the answer as accepted